MAUI Blazor Hybrid not loading simple startup template for Windows
I am trying to setup a brand new project using Visual Studio 2022, using template for MAUI Blazor Hybrid App with web app.
It creates 3 projects in a solution:

A web project (server side rendering)
A class library with 3 basic pages like counter and weather
A maui project

I have not changed anything in the code. It's exactly as the template generated it. So if you want to reproduce, just use that template as is and hit run.
The web project loads fine. I can see and interact with the pages.
The maui project, when I run as Windows application, just loads an empty purple background. No errors visible in the output window.
Has anyone come across this issue? Any ideas will be super helpful.
I am happy to share code, but as I said, not a single bit was added or changed by me. It's exactly just the output of the Visual Studio 2022 template.

ok, i haven't got to the bottom of it yet, but here is what i found so far: so the template works for web and windows app when I build and run on Intel based windows laptop. if I build and run inside a VM which is hosted on an Apple silicon Mac book pro, then I have the above issue. Apple silicon based Mac book was what i was using initially when i reported the issue.

It is an issue MAUI blazor example doesn't work on Windows on the Github you can check and follow up this thread.
You can try to to install WebView2 Runtime to fix this issue.
